# Pygame 'groupcollide'?

Tags: python, pygame

Below is part of my code for a 'Tetris' game.

What I want to do is simply to make the bottom of the falling shape equal in height(-1) to the top of the static shape, on collision. However, as it is, I can only set the contact position as the bottom of the moving shape; resulting in it appearing to sink into the shape it collides with (which throws off the whole 'block' illusion).

```
    stick = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(pieces_mobs, static_mobs, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
```

This is what I'm currently using because I'm not sure of how to access the second value in a 'groupcollide' tuple -

```
for piece in pieces_mobs:
    for instance in stick:
        contact = instance.rect.bottom
        instance.static(contact)
    piece.update()
```

This is the logic I want -

```
for piece in pieces_mobs:
    for pieces, static in stick:
        contact = static.rect.top
        pieces.static(contact)
    piece.update()
```

Probably really simple, but I just can't find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per pygame documentation, the output of groupcollide is a dictionary with the key being a sprite from the first group and the value a list of all the sprites from second group the key sprite is colliding with. So to achieve your goal:

```
stick = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(pieces_mobs, static_mobs, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

for piece_mob, static_mob in stick.items():
    piece_mob.rect.bottom = static_mob[0].rect.top
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was a dictionary. Thanks for your help.